# Resolving incorrect character encoding when displaying MySQL database results after upgrade to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

#### Issue Description

After upgrading PHP on our development server from 5.2 to 5.3, we're encountering an issue where data requested from our database and displayed on a web page shows with improper encoding when attempting to display Russian characters.

#### Environment

- Dev OS: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0
- Dev PHP: 5.3.5-0.dotdeb.1
- Live MySQL: Distrib 5.1.49

#### Details

In PHP 5.3, the default client library for interacting with MySQL databases changed from libmysql to [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php), which would appear to be the cause of the issue we are encountering.

We are connecting to the database with the following code:

```
$conn = mysql_pconnect('database.hostname', 'database_user', 'database_password');
$mysql_select_db('database', $conn);
```

The data stored in our database is encoded with UTF-8 encoding. Connecting to the database via the command-line client and running queries confirms that the data is intact and encoded properly. However, when we query the database in PHP and try to display the exact same data, it becomes garbled. In this specific case, we're attempting to display Russian characters and the result is non-English, non-Russian characters:
[image: garbled mess]

The response headers we receive confirm that the content-type is UTF-8:

[image: response headers]

We tested the strings before display with [mb_detect_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) in strict mode as well as [mb_check_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) and were told the string was a UTF-8 string before displaying it. We also used [mysql_client_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php) to test the client encoding and it also indicates the character set is UTF-8.

In performing research, we discovered [some suggestions](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/) to try to work around this issue:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_query("SET SESSION character_set_results = 'UTF8'");
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8', $conn);
```

We even tried [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php):

```
utf8_encode($string);
```

However, none of these solutions worked.

Running out of options, we upgraded MySQL on our development system to Distrib 5.1.55. After that upgrade, everything displayed correctly when we connected to our development database. Of course, it continues to display incorrectly when we connect to our live database.

Ideally, we would like to resolve this issue without upgrading MySQL on our production servers unless we can verify the exact reason why this isn't working and why the upgrade will fix it. **How can we resolve this encoding issue without upgrading MySQL? Alternatively, why does the MySQL upgrade fix the issue?**

Comment: What kind of garbled?  This sounds strongly like the default connection encoding is ISO-8859-1 in the garbled case, and UTF-8 in the non-garbled case. Don't know why.... What code are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: @Pekka: Updated the question to address your queries.

Comment: and your output encoding on the HTML end is UTF-8 too? Can you confirm the browser is in UTF-8 mode when entering your site?

Comment: @Pekka: yes, it is UTF-8 (I work with Shaun and I'm familiar with this problem we're having)

Comment: Random guess: Corrupted font cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have made sure that both the tables, and the output encoding are UTF-8, almost the only thing left is the connection encoding.

The reason for the change in behaviour when updating servers *could* be a change of the default connection encoding:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

However, I can't see any changes in the default encoding between versions, so if those were brand-new installs, I can't see that happening.

Anyway, what happens if you run this from within your PHP query and output the results. Any differences to the command line output?

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
```

Comment: @Andreas strange, looks okay. Do you do anything specific with the data, or do you just edit it?

Comment: @Pekka: if we just SELECT a russian field and then echo it, it's displayed that way. And yes all of this is very strange..

Comment: @Andreas any chance of a live link?

Comment: @Pekka That would be difficult as we're testing this on internal development systems. I have updated the question with a screenshot of the response headers as reported by Firebug. Is there any other additional information you'd want from a link?

Comment: @Shaun is "utf8" what the browser is showing in its encoding menu as well? Does it look okay if you force override it to ISO-8859-5 or one of the other cyrillic encodings?

Comment: @Pekka: The browser's menu shows "Unicode (UTF8)" as being selected. Trying to invoke ISO-8859-5 results in a mix of Cyrillic and garbled character output. I tried several other encoding methods marked as "Cyrillic" with similar results.

Comment: @Shaun that's weird, then it doesn't seem even to be "properly broken"... Very strange, I'm out of ideas! The next step might be trying to reproduce it on a different server install, and comparing the mySQL versions' settings side-by-side to see whether anything is different. Also check the tables and columns - you can specify custom encodings for each

Comment: @Pekka: As it turns out, you were on the right track with your initial answer. I reran the queries you suggested on our live server directly and got [different results than Andreas reported](http://codepad.org/NgUVyfOM). Running `status;` from the command-line also showed the difference in server vs client encoding. Once we forced our test scripts into using latin1, the text worked as expected. It would seem this discrepancy existed all along and the change in the MySQL client library during the upgrade to PHP 5.3 exposed it.

Comment: @Shaun ah, interesting! Thanks for the feedback. That also explains why the characters were "doubly" broken and not just single-byte representations of multi-byte data - cyrillic can't be displayed in latin1

Comment: @Pekka Indeed. Thanks for the assistance on this one. :)

Answer (score 4):

I see you've tried this, but the syntax I use is: mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"). Your syntax may be correct, I've just never seen it like that before.

Example:

```
// connect to database stuff
$Connection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password)
or die ("Error connecting to server");

// connect to database stuff
$db = mysql_select_db($database, $Connection)
or die ("Error selecting database");

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: Yeah, we're just supplying the optional second parameter to provide the connection (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). I tried it your way just for kicks (with the lowercase UTF and double quotes as well) and the results were the same: garbled text.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after upgrading PHP from 5.2.3 to 5.3.5 (5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86), MySQL 5.0.41 (not updated). I think that reason is a little difference between PHP versions.

PHP 5.2.3 default (without SET NAMES):
*character_set_client = latin1

character_set_connection = latin1

character_set_database = utf8

character_set_filesystem = binary

character_set_results = latin1

character_set_server = latin2

character_set_system = utf8

collation_connection = latin1_swedish_ci

collation_database = utf8_polish_ci

collation_server = latin2_general_ci*

PHP 5.3.5 default (without SET NAMES):
*character_set_client = latin2

character_set_connection = latin2

character_set_database = utf8

character_set_filesystem = binary

character_set_results = latin2

character_set_server = latin2

character_set_system = utf8

collation_connection = latin2_general_ci

collation_database = utf8_polish_ci

collation_server = latin2_general_ci*

I added data to database in PHP 5.2.3 default (without SET NAMES), so now to display it correctly I must read it using:

```
$pdo -> query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
```

Maybe something similar is reason of your problem.